# Jenkins Plugin ssh Publisher not able to copy file to ansible server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use Jenkins plugin "**ssh publisher**"  - **Transfer set** option.
I want to achieve two points with it .
firstly - copy some files from Jenkins server to Ansible Server.
secondly - touch a file on Ansible server.

Here are logs of my Build, which clearly shows that Jenkins server after building artifact , is able to ssh to ansible server.
**then it copied "0" file (Don't know why?)**
and finally touched file on ansible server (which is expected)

```
[INFO] Maven Project ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.457 s]
[INFO] Server ............................................. SUCCESS [  2.408 s]
[INFO] Webapp ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.777 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.806 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-05T08:52:42Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSH: Connecting from host [JenkinsMaster]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [ansible] ...
SSH: Creating session: username [amitadmin], hostname [ansible.amit.com], port [22]
SSH: Connecting session ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: Opening SFTP channel ...
SSH: SFTP channel open
SSH: Connecting SFTP channel ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: cd [.]
SSH: OK
SSH: Remote root is not absolute, getting absolute directory from PWD
SSH: Opening exec channel ...
SSH: EXEC: channel open
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [ touch 123.txt] ...
SSH: EXEC: connected
SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [ansible] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to SUCCESS
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Here is my configuration .

[image: Screen Shot of Jenkins]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved this step to post Build and it worked fine.